# Create folders in UITableView from saved images

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, directory

I have an `iOS` Xcode 7 project written in `Swift2`.  I'm saving photos to the app using `NSCoding`:

```
class UserImages: NSObject, NSCoding {

    // MARK: Properties
    var name: String
    var photo: NSData // UIImage

    ...
}
```

These images currently are shown in a `UITableView`:

```
class ImagesTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    // MARK: Properties

    var photos = [UserImages]()

    ...

    // MARK: TableView Details

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return photos.count

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellIdentifier = "ImageTableViewCell"

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageTableViewCell

        let photo = photos[indexPath.row]

        var image: NSData = photo.photo as NSData

        cell.nameLabel.text = photo.name

        cell.photoImageView.image = UIImage(data: image)

        return cell

    }

}
```

Works great, and in my custom cell, I have a `UILabel` and `UIImageView` for the name and photo.

My question is, how can I allow the user to create folders within the `UITableView` and allow the photos to be moved/organized in the folders?  I'd like to try and keep the NSCoding unless it's impossible to implement folders and still use NSCoding. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using `NSCoding` and instead saving everything with `CoreData`.  I setup an `Entity` called `Photos` and gave it `attributes` of:

```
name // Set as String
imageData // Set as Binary Data
folder // Set as String
```

The user then can add a new image and set the name of the photo and folder they want to put it in using `UITextFields`.

I then setup a `FolderTableViewController` displaying the `folders` from a `request` and in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` captured the image name from the selected cell and transferred it to a new `ViewController` which has a `UITableView` and displays the images from `FolderTableViewController` performing a `request.predicate`.

Works well for what I needed it to do.  May not be the most glamorous but it made sense and did what I needed it to.